# Robot framework Using yaml list in for loop

Tags: yaml, robotframework

I am having issues with a for loop.

Getting the error "FOR loop contains no keywords."

I have a yaml file that I import.

```
test_sequence_1:
  - test_name: "Test"
    test_items:
      - test_name1
      - test_name2
```

I then import it and am trying to iterate over it.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  BuiltIn
Library  Collections

Variables  ../vars/vrf_test_cases.yaml
*** Test Cases ***
Run Sequential Tests
    Launch test cases sequence  @{test_sequence_1}
```

That then runs the keyword, I've tried both the different for loops, and a variety of other options. I cannot for the life of me get the 2nd For loop to work

```
Launch test cases sequence
    #TODO add a default empty value for extra_vars_dict
    [Documentation]         Launch a given set of workflow templates from a yaml dictionary
    [Arguments]             @{test_sequence_dict}
    FOR  ${sequence}  IN  @{test_sequence_dict}
        Log to Console  \n\n\n Launching: ${sequence['test_name']}
        @{test_list}=    Convert To List    ${sequence['test_items']}
        Log to Console  \n Run Tests var: @{test_list}[0]
        #FOR  ${test}  IN  @{sequence['test_items']}
            #Log to Console  ${test}
            #Run Keyword  ${test}
        #END
        FOR  ${test}  IN  @{test_list}
            Log to Console  ${test}
        END        
    END
```

I feel like I've missed something, and wonder what is the missing part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested for loops are not supported in robot framework.

From the user guide, in the section titled [Nested for loops](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#nested-for-loops)

> Having nested for loops is not supported directly, but it is possible to use a user keyword inside a for loop and have another for loop there.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea, and didn't even think the issue was a nested loop.